# Excel Interop - How to search cell with format?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I see that Excel interop has [Find method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.range.find(v=office.15).aspx) but I don't know how to use it.

I want to search the cell, that has specific color, in the range (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range).
In Excel, you will do like this:

1. Ctrl + F to open 'Find and Replace' dialog. Leave the text box 'Find what:' Empty.
2. Click button [Options >>] or Alt+T
3. Click button [Format...] or Alt+M
4. Go to tab font -> Click Color option (Alt+C) and choose the color.
5. Click Ok, then click [Find Next]

I just want to programmatically do that with Excel Interop.

Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the `Application.FindFormat` property before calling the `Find()` method.

E.g. if you want to search for red cells using the standard settings of the "Find and Replace" dialog, you can use the following code:

```
// These are the search options of the "Format" dialog.
_application.FindFormat.Font.Color = 255;
_application.FindFormat.Font.TintAndShade = 0;

// cell is null if nothing was found.
var cell = _application.Cells.Find(What: "", After: _application.ActiveCell,
    LookIn: XlFindLookIn.xlFormulas, LookAt: XlLookAt.xlPart,
    SearchOrder: XlSearchOrder.xlByRows, SearchDirection: XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
    // It's important to set SearchFormat to true.
    MatchCase: false, SearchFormat: true);
```

If you want to search for the accent color 2 of the current theme, you can do this as well:

```
_application.FindFormat.Font.ThemeColor = XlThemeColor.xlThemeColorAccent2;
```

If you want to emulate the exact behavior of the "Find and Replace" dialog, you can call `cell.Activate()` after you found the cell.